# APScheduler jobs disappearing

Tags: python, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, apscheduler

**EDIT:** Solved! The problem was not related to APScheduler in any way. The code was running as service in AWS ECS and crashed and restarted every time because of insufficient memory. I didn't notice it crashed and restarted because there was no exception (probably the whole container crashed) so I just thought that only the first jobs were running.

I'm building a program in python that uses APScheduler to schedule different jobs.

The code looks something like that:

```
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

# Let's say parameters = ['p1', 'p2'...] The real value does not matter
for p in parameters:
    scheduler.add_job(func=func1, args=(p,),  # Sometimes there is more than on argument
                      id=f'{p}-func1',
                      trigger='interval',
                      minutes=5,
                      max_instances=1,
                      misfire_grace_time=60)
    
    # A lot more jobs with function like that: func2, func3...

scheduler.start()
```

**Not for all function max_instances and misfire_grace_time are defined.**

Later in the logs, I see a lot more (more than 3-4 times) logs from the first parameters (p1, p2) than from the last parameters (p20, p21...) while it needs to be the same (or at least very close to it)

I thought it may be related to the number of workers because I have about 20 parameters and 20 functions which can lead to 400 jobs running very close to each other. So I tried to increase it by doing:

```
executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(1000),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(1000)
}
scheduler = BlockingScheduler(executors=executors)
```

But I can't say that helped.

Does anyone have an Idea what could affect such drastic change in the number of jobs being done for each parameter and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Are you saying that the later jobs are *never* executed? Have you followed the troubleshooting procedures laid out in the documentation?

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was related to something else entirely and not to APSchedualer...